# How can I downloand .zip dependency via gradle?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I want to download not-jar file from repository. I want to do it via task. I have this code but it does nothing when I call the function.

```
repositories {
   maven {
      url: abc.com
   }
}

configurations { archives { transitive = false } }
dependencies { archives "group:programm:version1" } // this file exists in abc.com with .zip extension 

task getArchives(type: Sync){
   from configurations.archives
   into "dest_dir"
}
```

abc.com is artifactory, but don't think that it is relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working example, you can change the task to your extract.

```
configurations {
    zipDist
}

dependencies {
    zipDist 'org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:6.0-6@zip'
}

task testZip(type: Zip) {
    from configurations.zipDist
}

artifacts {
    zipDist testZip
}
```